# How to use belongs_to to the same model but for different columns (for meaning)

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model Group.

A group can have many addresses as locations.  It has to have two kinds of other addresses for sure:
one for a mailing address
one for a billing address

So Address is a Model too, how do I have a belongs_to to the same model but with
multiple ids?

i.e.

Group:
      mailing_address_id
      billing_address_id

The various locations is taken care of by a group_locations join table easy enough:
id
group_id
address_id

But how do I use the belongs_to for the mailing_address_id and biling_address_id ???  normally it would be:

address_id (like it is in the join) but I need them to *mean* something.

this is an artifact of me wanting to seperate out the addresses into another table trying to keep the database relatively normalized I think it is called.

I also had a heck of a time building another kind of a join table that joins people in a group through the locations join table...but that is a diff topic I posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599419/building-a-migration-for-a-join-table-based-on-a-join-table-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: billing_address, class: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
  belongs_to: mailing_address, class: 'Address', foreign_key: 'mailing_address_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

you can try :foreign_key on your relation.

look for "4.1.2.5 :foreign_key" section on [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign
>   key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id
>   added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign
>   key directly

Answer (score 1):

An address is just an address so should get its own table.

A person may be located at an address and use it in a role.

Two people could live at the same address. Both for home, and one for work. Therefore:

```
create table addresses (
  address_id int primary key,
  ...address info...
);

create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  ...person info...
);

create table people_placements (
  person_id int references people(person_id),
  address_id int references addresses(address_id),
  address_role_id smallint references address_roles(address_role_id), /* definition elided */

  primary key (person_id, address_id, addres_role_id)
);
```

For a sales order you would reference the people_placements table for the billing party and address. Same for shipping party and address on your sales order line items.